# ImportError blpapi in Python

Tags: python, c++, api, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm trying to use blpapi in python. Since my company has a strict firewall, I had to do an offline install of the latest one from condaforge ('blpapi-3.17.1-py38_blpapicpp3.16.1.1_1'). I've tried nearly every solution on stackoverflow including:

- Pasted the matching C++ SDK dll libraries for C++ 3.17.1.1 into the DAPI folder and anaconda site packages.
- Also pasted the dll files in system32 and tried running import blapi with os.add_dll_directory function.
- Added the bin and lib C++ SDK dll paths to the system environment PATH as well as in Spyder.
- Installed Visual Studio and the relevant C++ MFC, C++/CLI support, MSVC v143 tools etc.

````
---------------------------- ENVIRONMENT -----------------------------
Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Architecture: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
Python: 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python implementation: CPython

This Python version does not use PATH to find dlls
blpapi package at: "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages"

Current directory: "C:\blp\blpapi_cpp_3.17.1.1\lib"

----------------------------------------------------------------------
DLL load failed while importing _versionhelper: The specified module could not be found.

Could not open the C++ SDK library.

Download and install the latest C++ SDK from:

    http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/api-library

If the C++ SDK is already installed, Python 3.8+ on Windows requires that the
path to the library is added to 'add_dll_directory', i.e.:

    with os.add_dll_directory('<path to blpapi dlls>'):
        import blpapi```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According to this: https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/ the latest version of the Python api comes bundled with the C++ dlls you need.

Comment: @DS_London - I've tried the latest APIs but and it still doesn't work. I was even able to import blpapi at my personal PC without even having the Bloomberg Terminal and it worked. I copy pasted the same dlls to my work PC but I get the same error.