# Using Bloomberg API for automated daily close prices

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

My company is trying to get daily close prices of some publicly traded companies. I am looking into using Bloomberg API, but it is not very clear which product is the best to use. Here are some of my requirements:

1. Ideally, I would need this process automated and running every weekday.
2. I would like to use the Python API (blpapi) for getting this info.
3. If possible, it would be best if this could be integrated within GCP.

I have been given access to Bloomberg Data License temporarily, but it is not clear how to get to using blpapi from there. Some posts (like [this](https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python)) mention that C++ SDK is needed for manual installation, while [this](https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72996466/importerror-blpapi-in-python) says C++ API installation is no longer required. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74284145/subscription-fees-to-use-blpapi-package) post also says there should be a Bloomberg product installed to connect the API.

For my use case, what exactly do I need in terms of licenses, products, and is there a good description of setting it all up? In the end, I need to be able to use the blpapi library to get close prices. I can worry about automation and GCP later.

Comment: If you got a data license, BBG can help you with the installation steps. If not, you will need to have the Bloomberg software up and running.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on Bloomberg's website has all the information you need. If you are using python, "wheels now come bundled with the required C++ API, and a separate C++ API installation is no longer required."

There is also documentation on their site for using and developing with their SDK (in your case python) although there are no examples of python that I could quickly find there you should be able to understand the general workflow and required inputs and received outputs by looking at the examples they do provide.

In general you have to perform some authentication before you can access data with a service that has pricing; even some that are free require authentication. Once you are authenticated then for your case you need to view examples of how to get the current or closing price. Basically I suggest you do some reading of their documentation, try to implement the examples using python, then if necessary ask more targeted/specific questions here.

https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/
https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/
https://bloomberg.github.io/blpapi-docs/python/3.20/ (change to your version of python)